# Do we need to restart hadoop after making changes in the xml configuration files in Hadoop conf directory?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

Suppose I change the port numbers for tasktrackers or change the number of maximum map tasks through the conf files in hadoop, do I need to stop and restart the servers/daemons?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what options you change, but for the two examples you provide i would say yes, restart the mapred services (you don't need to restart the DFS services for these options).

I don't think there is an exhaustive list anywhere of what you need to restart when you amend a specific option.